# How to use the secondary mac's keyboard when using Target Display Mode

Tags: target-display

I basically want to be able to connect my MacBook to my stationary Mac and  use the keyboard and mouse on the MacBook. Is this possible? Ideally using standard software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what [Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) does. The only caveats are that "stationary Mac" must be an iMac that supports Target Display Mode, and you must have a keyboard connected to the iMac to turn Target Display Mode on and off.

> Follow these steps to start using your iMac as a display:
>
> - Make sure both computers are turned on.
> - Connect the Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt cable between the two computers.
> - Press Command-F2 on the keyboard of the iMac that you want to use as a display.
>
> After you press Command-F2, your iMac displays the desktop from the connected Mac.